# select values from two columns and display as one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with two columns  [Date], [StopName],  i want to write a query which will show both columns as one column  like e.g.  12/05/2007: Stop1. So far i was trying like this

```
SELECT  Date + ':' + StopName as Departure from tbldept.
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: `+` is for adding numbers (or date arithmetics), `||` is the operator to concatenate character values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  to_char(Date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') || ':' || to_char(StopName) as Departure 
from tbldept.
```

`||` is concatenation operator just like in Oracle

**UPDT** fixed to avoid conversion errors

Answer (score 0):

You are right, in may get conversion failed error. In that case you need convert the column into a varchar data type.